# Set ProgressBar in Cursor while SQLite

Tags: android

How I can set dynamically set the progressbar status after reading a value from db SQLite?

I have this code.

```
int i = 0;
while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
   i++;
   pb.setProgress(i)
}
```

But my problem is that progress bar is update only at finish while so without "liveEffect"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem with Handler and Thread.sleep (for simulate live)

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      do {
         mProgressStatus++;
         try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               pb.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
            }
         );
      } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use runOnUiThread method of Activity class:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        pb.setProgress(i);
    }
});
```

More here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, execution time is too low that by  live effect not appear . take large cursor around 10000 value then apply loop now you can see progress

Comment: thankyou, but if I use breakpoint not work. so I believe there is a problem with setProgress

Comment: if your code running in main thread then no issue. otherwise run your code in main threa d

Comment: thankyou I have resolved with handler.post and Thread.sleep. I will post my solution